# NextJS - Maximum call stack size exceeded when adding "use client" to my component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, next.js14

I am working on a project to practice NextJS where I am making a clone of Threads. I have a component called ThreadCard where the styling and configuration of each Thread is specified.

```
// ThreadCard.tsx

import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";
import { formatDateTime, formatRelativeTime } from "@/lib/utils";

interface Props {
  id: string;
  currentUser: string;
  parentId: string | null;
  content: string;
  author: {
    name: string;
    image: string;
    id: string;
    username: string;
  }
  createdAt: string;
  comments: {
    author: {
      image: string;
    }
  }[];
  isComment?: boolean;
  isDetailed?: boolean;
}

const ThreadCard = ({
  id,
  content,
  author,
  createdAt,
  comments,
  isComment=false,
  isDetailed=false,
}: Props) => {
  return (
    <article className={`flex w-full flex-col rounded-xl bg-gray-900 p-7 ${!isComment ? 'xs:px-7' : 'bg-gray-950'}`}>
      <div className="flex items-start justify-between">
        <div className="flex w-full flex-1 flex-row gap-4">
          <div className="flex flex-col items-center">
            <Link href={`/profile/${author.id }`} className="relative h-11 w-11">
              <Image 
                src={author.image}
                alt='profile photo'
                fill
                className="cursor-pointer rounded-full"
              />
            </Link>

            <div className="relative mt-2 w-0.5 grow rounded-full bg-gray-700" />
          </div>

          <div className="flex w-full flex-col">
            <Link href={`/profile/${author.id }`} className="w-fit flex gap-1 items-center">
              <h4 className="cursor-pointer font-semibold text-white text-lg hover:underline transition-all">{author.name}</h4>
              <p className="text-gray-400 text-lg font-thin">@{author.username}</p>
              {!isDetailed && (
                <p className="text-gray-400 text-lg font-thin"> · {formatRelativeTime(createdAt)}</p>
              )}
            </Link>

            <p className="mt-2 text-white text-base font-light">{content}</p>

            {isDetailed && (
              <p className="mt-7 mb-1 text-gray-500 font-light text-sm">{formatDateTime(createdAt)}</p>
            )}

            <div className={`${isDetailed ? 'mt-1' : 'mt-5'} flex flex-col gap-3`}>
              <div className="flex gap-3.5">
                <Image src="/assets/heart-gray.svg" alt="heart" width={24} height={24} className="cursor-pointer object-contain filter hover:brightness-0 hover:invert hover:transition-colors" />
                
                <Link href={`/thread/${id}`} className="flex gap-1 items-center justify-center">
                  <Image src="/assets/reply.svg" alt="reply" width={24} height={24} className="cursor-pointer object-contain filter hover:brightness-0 hover:invert hover:transition-colors" />
                  <p className="font-extralight text-sm text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-200 transition-colors">{comments.length > 0 ? `${comments.length}` : ''} </p>
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  )
}

export default ThreadCard
```

I then render this on my homepage where I fetch all the threads and display them.

```
// app > (root) > page.tsx

import ThreadCard from "@/components/cards/ThreadCard";
import { fetchThreads } from "@/lib/actions/thread.actions";
import { currentUser } from "@clerk/nextjs";

export default async function Home() {
  const result = await fetchThreads(1, 30);
  const user = await currentUser();

  return (
    <>
      <section className="mt-9 flex flex-col gap-10">
        {result.threads.length === 0 ? (
          <p className="text-center font-light text-white">No Threads found.</p>
        ) : (
          <>
            {result.threads.map((thread) => (
              <ThreadCard
                key={thread._id}
                id={thread._id}
                currentUser={user?.id || ""}
                parentId={thread.parentId}
                content={thread.text}
                author={thread.author}
                createdAt={thread.createdAt}
                comments={thread.children}
              />
            ))}
          </>
        )}
      </section>
    </>
  )
}
```

It works perfectly fine, but I want to add a "like" functionality. I will use useState in the ThreadCard to manage the state of each Thread being liked or not. This means I need to add "use client" at the top of the ThreadCard.tsx. This is where the problem occurs.

Simply adding "use client" causes the app to not work and display this error:
[Call stack error when I add "use client" to ThreadCard.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApGTd.png)

Here is another place where ThreadCard component is rendered (individual page for the thread):

```
// app > (root) > thread > [id] > page.tsx

import ThreadCard from "@/components/cards/ThreadCard";
import Reply from "@/components/forms/Reply";
import { fetchThreadById } from "@/lib/actions/thread.actions";
import { fetchUser } from "@/lib/actions/user.actions";
import { currentUser } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

const Page = async ({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) => {
  if(!params.id) return null;

  const user = await currentUser();
  if(!user) return null;

  const userInfo = await fetchUser(user.id);
  if(!userInfo.onboarded) redirect('/onboarding')

  const thread = await fetchThreadById(params.id);

  return (
    <section className="relative">
      <div>
        <ThreadCard
          key={thread._id}
          id={thread._id}
          currentUser={user?.id || ""}
          parentId={thread.parentId}
          content={thread.text}
          author={thread.author}
          createdAt={thread.createdAt}
          comments={thread.children}
          isDetailed
        />
      </div>

      <div className="mt-7">
        <Reply 
          threadId={thread.id}
          currentUserImg={userInfo.image}
          currentUserId={JSON.stringify(userInfo._id)}
        />
      </div>
      
      <div className="mt-10">
        {thread.children.map((child: any) => (
          <ThreadCard 
            key={child._id}
            id={child._id}
            currentUser={user?.id || ""}
            parentId={child.parentId}
            content={child.text}
            author={child.author}
            createdAt={child.createdAt}
            comments={child.children}
            isComment
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Page;
```

If there is no "use client" in ThreadsCard.tsx, it works perfectly fine. I am at a loss on what the cause of this issue is.

Comment: The error message talks about max call stack limits so there must be some issue with recursion and it also mentions `String.replace`. I imagine with the "right" data you could also potentially get the same issue with server components too; it doesn't seem like it's actually related to making ThreadCard a client component. From what's shared, I can't really say much more but it looks like adding lifecycle to your component makes it hit this error easier than the "one and done" render of a server component.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a function in the parent screen too and pass it as a prop in ThreadCard component

```
// app > (root) > page.tsx

import ThreadCard from "@/components/cards/ThreadCard";
import { fetchThreads } from "@/lib/actions/thread.actions";
import { currentUser } from "@clerk/nextjs";

export default async function Home() {
  const result = await fetchThreads(1, 30);
  const user = await currentUser();

  const onLike = (id: number | string) => {
    // like logic
  }

  return (
    <>
      <section className="mt-9 flex flex-col gap-10">
        {result.threads.length === 0 ? (
          <p className="text-center font-light text-white">No Threads found.</p>
        ) : (
          <>
            {result.threads.map((thread) => (
              <ThreadCard
                key={thread._id}
                id={thread._id}
                currentUser={user?.id || ""}
                parentId={thread.parentId}
                content={thread.text}
                author={thread.author}
                createdAt={thread.createdAt}
                comments={thread.children}
                isLiked={thread.like} //change it accordingly
                onLike={onLike}
              />
            ))}
          </>
        )}
      </section>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: "Maybe you are using "use client" in the wrong way" does not sound like you're sure this answer fixes the issue.

Comment: @possum he has not specified where he is using "use client" in the code but still I have given other answer

Comment: @possum I add the "use client" in the ThreadCard.tsx. Upon adding that, it instantly throws the call stack error. Without the "use client", it works fine

Comment: @randomdevph have you tried the solution?